# Convert redundant array to dict (or JSON)?

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

Suppose I have an array:

```
[['a', 10, 1, 0.1],
 ['a', 10, 2, 0.2],
 ['a', 20, 2, 0.3],
 ['b', 10, 1, 0.4],
 ['b', 20, 2, 0.5]]
```

And I want a `dict` (or JSON):

```
{
    'a': {
        10: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2},
        20: {2: 0.3}
    }
    'b': {
        10: {1: 0.4},
        20: {2: 0.5}
    }
}
```

Is there any good way or some library for this task?
In this example the array is just 4-column, but my original array is more complicated (7-column).

Currently I implement this naively:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
grouped1 = df.groupby('column1')
for column1 in grouped1.groups:
    group1 = grouped1.get_group(column1)
    grouped2 = group1.groupby('column2')
    for column2 in grouped2.groups:
        group2 = grouped2.get_group(column2)
        ...
```

And `defaultdict` way:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda x: defaultdict(lambda y: defaultdict ... ))
for row in array:
    d[row[0]][row[1]][row[2]... = row[-1]
```

But I think neither is smart.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Do you mean `['a', 10, 2, 0.2]` as the second element of your list, or the program also has to converts `['a', 10, 1, 0.2]` to `['a', 10, 2, 0.2]`?

Comment: @KevinGuan sorry, I mistyped and edited my question. Each key column (columns except the last column) should be unique. (At least, I will remove duplicates in advance)

Comment: What is the expected output, if each inner list has odd number of elements?

Comment: The last elements of each inner list are the values of most nested dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Here is a recursive solution. The base case is when you have a list of 2-element lists (or tuples), in which case, the `dict` will do what we want:

```
>>> dict([(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2)])
{1: 0.1, 2: 0.2}
```

For other cases, we will remove the first column and recurse down until we get to the base case.

## The code:

```
from itertools import groupby

def rows2dict(rows):
    if len(rows[0]) == 2:
        # e.g. [(1, 0.1), (2, 0.2)] ==> {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2}
        return dict(rows)
    else:
        dict_object = dict()
        for column1, groupped_rows in groupby(rows, lambda x: x[0]):
            rows_without_first_column = [x[1:] for x in groupped_rows]
            dict_object[column1] = rows2dict(rows_without_first_column)
        return dict_object

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rows = [['a', 10, 1, 0.1],
            ['a', 10, 2, 0.2],
            ['a', 20, 2, 0.3],
            ['b', 10, 1, 0.4],
            ['b', 20, 2, 0.5]]
    dict_object = rows2dict(rows)
    print dict_object
```

## Output

```
{'a': {10: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2}, 20: {2: 0.3}}, 'b': {10: {1: 0.4}, 20: {2: 0.5}}}
```

## Notes

- We use the `itertools.groupby` generator to simplify grouping of similar rows based on the first column
- For each group of rows, we remove the first column and recurse down
- This solution assumes that the `rows` variable has 2 or more columns. The result is unpreditable for rows which has 0 or 1 column.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest this rather simple solution:

```
from functools import reduce

data = [['a', 10, 1, 0.1],
        ['a', 10, 2, 0.2],
        ['a', 20, 2, 0.3],
        ['b', 10, 1, 0.4],
        ['b', 20, 2, 0.5]]

result = dict()
for row in data:
    reduce(lambda v, k: v.setdefault(k, {}), row[:-2], result)[row[-2]] = row[-1]

print(result)
```

```
{'a': {10: {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2}, 20: {2: 0.3}}, 'b': {10: {1: 0.4}, 20: {2: 0.5}}}
```

An actual recursive solution would be something like this:

```
def add_to_group(keys: list, group: dict):
    if len(keys) == 2:
        group[keys[0]] = keys[1]
    else:
        add_to_group(keys[1:], group.setdefault(keys[0], dict()))

result = dict()
for row in data:
    add_to_group(row, result)

print(result)
```